# How to resolve the error "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

Tags: oracle

I have been getting the error ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected and do not know why:

```
    SELECT
units_dt.unit_id,
units_dt.archive_unit_code as case_code,

(select 
    case tr.tr_type_id
    when 10 then (select AC_RSTR_TPS.NAME from BS_C_AC_RSTR_TPS AC_RSTR_TPS 
    left JOIN BS_C_UNIT_RSTRS_DT RSTRS_DT on RSTRS_DT.UNIT_ID = UNITS_DT.UNIT_ID
    where AC_RSTR_TPS.ID = 8 and AC_RSTR_TPS.ID = RSTRS_DT.RESTRICTION_TYPE_ID)
    end from dual ) as TRANSACTION_RSTRS


FROM BS_C_UNITS_DT units_dt
LEFT JOIN BS_TRANSACTIONS TR on TR.UNIT_ID = UNITS_DT.UNIT_ID
LEFT JOIN BS_TR_TYPES TR_TYPES on TR_TYPES.ID = TR.TR_TYPE_ID
LEFT JOIN BS_C_UNITS UNITS on UNITS.ID = UNITS_DT.UNIT_ID  

where units_dt.LU_DATE >= to_date('13/02/2012 09:10:01', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
and units_dt.LU_DATE <= to_date('13/02/2012 09:55:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
and TR_TYPES.ID IN(2,10,15)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect syntax in the `CASE` expression inside the subquery.  Use this instead:

```
SELECT
    units_dt.unit_id,
    units_dt.archive_unit_code as case_code,
    (
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN tr.tr_type_id = 10
                 THEN
                 (
                     SELECT AC_RSTR_TPS.NAME
                     FROM BS_C_AC_RSTR_TPS AC_RSTR_TPS 
                     LEFT JOIN BS_C_UNIT_RSTRS_DT RSTRS_DT
                         ON RSTRS_DT.UNIT_ID = UNITS_DT.UNIT_ID
                     WHERE AC_RSTR_TPS.ID = 8 AND
                           AC_RSTR_TPS.ID = RSTRS_DT.RESTRICTION_TYPE_ID
                 )
            END
        FROM dual
    ) AS TRANSACTION_RSTRS
FROM BS_C_UNITS_DT units_dt
...
```

If you work on improving the formatting of your query, it will make it much easier to spot mistakes like the one in your OP.

Comment: [Err] ORA-00904: "UNITS_DT"."UNIT_ID": invalid identifier ((((((((((((((

Comment: Break your query into smaller pieces until you get something working, then add back the complexity slowly.  And stop changing your question.  My answer addressed the original problem with your `CASE` statement.